# Less Verbose Error Messages Ipython

Tags: python-2.7, ipython

Please help this is driving me stir crazy. I am using Ipython Shell, and desperately trying to receive less verbose error messages. For each tiny error I am getting 40+ lines. I think what I need to do is set xmode to plain. I tried at first to do this in the command prompt upon starting ipython, but I think xmode is a magic function so should be called in the Ipython shell, so I wont paste what I tried in the command prompt. In the shell I tried:

```
xmode('Plain')
xmode('plain')
xmode(plain)
xmode(Plain)
```

and all of the above with a % prefix. I also tried

```
xmode<('Plain')>
```

and about a billion other permutations.

Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong....?

Thanks so much

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Magics are usually called without parentheses, and with a leading percent. You can call them without % in some cases I wont detail here.

xmode called without argument will cycle by itself through option. 
Here is a session of mine :

```
In [1]: xmode
Exception reporting mode: Verbose

In [2]: %xmode
Exception reporting mode: Plain

In [3]: %xmode
Exception reporting mode: Context

In [4]: %xmode
Exception reporting mode: Verbose

In [5]: %xmode plain
Exception reporting mode: Plain

In [6]: %xmode plain
Exception reporting mode: Plain
```

Hope that helps. You can also execute a single question mark `In[1]: ?` to get an intro to ipython, or see `%quickref`.

Comment: Oh my word that was so simple! I thought the % convention for calling magic functions was turned off by default, for example I never have to write %paste when pasting multiple text lines of code. Thank you so much!

Comment: % is optional by default unless the name would shadow anything in user namespace. so rule of thumb `%magic` will **always** work. `magic` might work in most cases when it is unambiguous.